# Replacing ships after taking control of enemy ports

Tags: game-of-thrones

Page 25 of the rulebook states:

> Taking Control of Enemy Ports - If the land area connected to a Port
>   is successfully attacked and taken control of by another player, that
>   player may immediately replace any enemy Ship units in the Port with
>   an equal number of his **own available Ship units** (or as many Ship units
>   as he has available, he desires, or is allowed by supply limits).
>   Excess enemy ships are simply removed from the board.

What does *available* mean in this context? Available as in a player has ships left that (s)he has not yet mustered or available as in ships that have already been mustered?

Where do the own ships come from? Are they *existing* ships on the board that simply move into the port now or are *new* ships mustered instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Available here means ships that are still in your supply. Use only those ships, not ones from the board.

You may find this useful from Page 4:

> **Exceeding the Components Provided**
>   Each House is provided a limited number of units,
>   tokens, and cards. If a player is using all his components of
>   a particular type, he may not bring additional components
>   of that type into play. Units that are destroyed in combat (or
>   removed from the board for any other reason) are available to
>   be mustered again.